# Repeat column headers in google sheets formula / query

Tags: google-sheets, google-forms

I have a google form setup to receive submissions into a google sheet. The data that comes through is in wide form, I am attempting to get it in long form.

Incoming Sample:

Timestamp   |  Name   |    Question 1a |    Response 1r     | Score
2/15/2024   | Joe     |     (Null)     |     1r value       |1s  value

Desired Result:

Timestamp |   Name |  Question   |   Response |        Score
2/15/2024 |   Joe  |   Q1        |   1r value |       1s value
2/15/2024     Joe     Q2             2r value        2s value

However, I can't repeat the column headers as these only contain the questions without associated values.

Here is the link to the workbook: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1GQjLN1JKN16pm8GWm7WXalkYiWHf9KrDT-CWV8fFqn8/edit#gid=1257586209

I'm 90 % there with this formula but I'm not sure how to repeat the column headers as associated questions:

=SORT(QUERY({'Form Responses'!A:E,'Form Responses'!F:H;'Form Responses'!A:E,'Form Responses'!I:K;'Form Responses'!A:E,'Form Responses'!L:N;'Form Responses'!A:E,'Form Responses'!O:Q}, "select * ",0))

Comment: The shared sheet has *restricted access*

Comment: @rockinfreakshow thank you for pointing this out. I corrected, the workbook is now unrestricted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Slightly adjusting your current formula to:*

```js
=let(Σ,rows('Form Responses'!A2:A),
     query(vstack({'Form Responses'!A2:E,wrapcols('Form Responses'!F1,Σ,'Form Responses'!F1),'Form Responses'!G2:H},{'Form Responses'!A2:E,wrapcols('Form Responses'!I1,Σ,'Form Responses'!I1),'Form Responses'!J2:K},{'Form Responses'!A2:E,wrapcols('Form Responses'!L1,Σ,'Form Responses'!L1),'Form Responses'!M2:N},{'Form Responses'!A2:E,wrapcols('Form Responses'!O1,Σ,'Form Responses'!O1),'Form Responses'!P2:Q}),
            "where Col1 is not null order by Col1"))
```

[image]

Comment: This works! You are the best, thank you so much, I'll look into the wrapcols function more. This is exactly what I needed!